# C# - WPF - Design time custom control isses (Take Two)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, design-time

In my original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41230436/c-sharp-wpf-design-time-custom-control-issues), I tried to make an inherited control from DockPanel. That ultimately failed so now I remade the control using a bare class. However, I am running into similar issues. During design-time, I need to place other controls inside a container within the custom control (a grid currently) and be able to select and edit them in the designer.

DockPanel.cs

```
[ContentProperty("OtherContent")]
public class DockPanel : ContentControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /* ... other properties etc goes above here ... */

    private object gContent = new Control();
    public object OtherContent
    {
        get { return gContent; }
        set { gContent = value; OnPropertyChanged("OtherContent"); }
    }

    public DockPanel()
    {
        //Setup default values for all other controls here..
        This.Content = BdrCtrl; // probably should use SetValue() for this.
        BdrCtrl.Child = gCtrl; //border that holds the main grid control so I can apply rounded corners.
        OtherContent = new Control();
        gCtrl.Children.Add(OtherContent as Control); 

         //  gctrl == grid that's a child of a border which is a child of DockPanel 
         //  itself. There's also a header being added for title etc as well.
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Controls:DockPanel Title="Explorer">
     <Button Content="Test"/>      
</Controls:DockPanel>
```

The button does not show up at design-time or run-time. I cannot drag any control onto the custom control that does not replace DockPanel.Content either. What am I missing? I cannot use bindings in the XAML because that defeats the purpose of being able to drag controls into it.

Here is the full class: http://pastebin.com/KYB7y9aU

Comment: What is `gCtrl` and why do you expect its children to appear in your DockPanel subclass? For that matter, I don't see anything in your code that makes any attempt to display `OtherContent` anywhere. Secondly, don't use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for controls. Use dependency properties for controls. The two kinds of properties are different.

Comment: Gctrl is the grid container that is a child of a border which is the child of DockPanel. Oh, whoops I forgot the one line that added it to the border. I will update code.

Comment: Okay code updated. I will try out a dependency property and get back to you.

Comment: Turning some random property into a dependency property isn't going to fix the problem you have.

Comment: Yeah, I had that in actual code.. updated post to reflect that.

Comment: "probably should use SetValue() for this" -- what's your reasoning there? But that's a side issue. Main issue: I need you to provide complete code for your control. And you need to explain the mechanism whereby you expect that `Button` in your XAML snippet to find its way into the children of `gCtrl` or anything else.

Comment: *"I cannot use bindings in the XAML because that defeats the purpose of being able to drag controls into it."* -- what bindings can't you use in what XAML on which properties, and how would that defeat the purpose of dragging what controls into it? And when? And how are you dragging them?

Comment: Here is the full class. http://pastebin.com/KYB7y9aU

Comment: Please put it in the question. Nobody around here is going to download your code from pastebin.

Comment: I am used to Winforms where just setting something as a parent causes it to render as the child. Also, I'd like to be able to drag a control from the toolbox into the DockPanel an for would add it as a child of Other content and be editable.

Comment: I don't see you setting anything as a parent anywhere. I have to say also, I'm not familiar with how the WPF toolbox works. Never used it once in five years.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I didn't even know there is such thing as wpf toolbox :)